# Power BI Automations of Audits and APIs

Tags: authentication, powerbi, dataset, workspace

How to bypass authentication key when creating audit reports using API.
Every time I access a report using API I need to get a code in order to refresh the data and access the information.

I want to bypass the authentication code.